# Terraform forces new ec2 resource creation on plan/apply regarding existing security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I've got a very simple piece of Terraform code:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

module ec2 {
  source = "./ec2_instance"
  name = "EC2 Instance 1"
}
```

where the module is:

```
variable "name" {
    default = "Default Name from ec2_instance.tf"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami = "ami-e5083683"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  subnet_id = "subnet-3e976259"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  security_groups = [ "sg-7310e10b" ]
  tags {
    Name = "${var.name}"
  }
}
```

When I first run it I get this output:

```
security_groups.#:            "" => "1"
security_groups.1642973399:   "" => "sg-7310e10b"
```

However, the next time I try a `plan` I get:

```
  security_groups.#:            "0" => "1" (forces new resource)
  security_groups.1642973399:   "" => "sg-7310e10b" (forces new resource)
```

What gives?!

Comment: Note that you are mixing up `default` and `description` on your variable.

Comment: What version of Terraform and the AWS provider are you running? Also you should really be using `vpc_security_group_ids` instead of `security_groups` when creating instances inside a VPC. See the docs for this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#security_groups

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are incorrectly assigning a `vpc_security_group_id` into  `security_groups`, instead of into `vpc_security_group_ids`.

Change

```
security_groups = [ "sg-7310e10b" ]
```

to

```
vpc_security_group_ids = [ "sg-7310e10b" ]
```

and everything will be ok.

Comment: `security_groups` refers to ec2-classic that runs on flat network and probably get reinitiated on each creation, `vpc_security_group_ids` is the modern and standard way for associate firewall rules to your ec2 in a vpc netwrok - therefore it's persisted and you should pick this one, It won't initiate and recreate itself on each terraform apply.